# Cómo manejar correctamente token de autenticación en react

Tags: reactjs, autenticación, tokens

estoy consumiendo una api para el login de una aplicación web con react, la api me retorna un token, un token de expiración y un tiempo de expiración del token. Mi pregunta es ¿cómo debería manejara correctamente estos elementos? Mi idea actual es almacenar el token y el refresh token en el localstorage, pero ¿cómo debería hacer con el tiempo de expiración del token?

Comment: el tiempo de expiración debería ser en el backend. En react cuando hagas un fetch a un endpoint y te retorne 401, entonces eliminas la sesión del usuario

Comment: gracias por una de las aclaraciones, pero... ¿el refresh token? he leído el uso de un middleware pero no encuentro una manera de hacerlo.